# Designing a high-volume market data service for WPF application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wcf

I wanted to create my own mini-project with fictitious high-volume data (options trading) to be consumed by a WPF application, to better understand the design concepts and considerations that go into designing a real-time system and want to learn what sort of techniques and approaches are used. Please no mention of third party solutions like Tibco - this is for learning purposes. My intention is the WPF application refreshes its UI every 5 seconds

When designing my fictitious market data server, given that high-volume performance is a criteria a few quick ideas come to mind - multicast UDP (is this too low-level / a bad direction?), a messaging architecture using a queue eg MSMQ or RabbitMQ, a remote service host the client app initiates requests to eg via WCF TCP binding or web-service.

One thought I had was the clients maintain their own local queues and subscribe to topics that the pricing server broadcasts using a messaging solution? Or maybe the server would broadcast the data to all clients equally and leave it to the clients to filter and collate the data locally? In peoples experiences, what are the pros and cons of each approach and is there any other approach I missed here? I guess it comes down to - should the client be pulling data or should the server be pushing it out to them?

The other question is - what would the wire-format would these messages take? I'm primarily used to working with rich business object classes, separated into a repository layer, domain model (with methods for validation and workflow logic) and simple service layer. Could I still leverage this approach and still maintain my performance goals or would I need to create a more light-weight data payload format?

Comment: There is a related open source project: http://github.com/kriasoft/market-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would start designing such a system from the higher layers before going down to network level optimizations.

RabbitMQ provides different types of exchanges for routing messages. The approach of broadcasting  all messages to every client (fanout exchange) is marginally fast on the RabbitMQ server side, but this will only work efficiently for low volume messages and provided the clients are connected via high speed links (e.g. local gigabit ethernet). Instead using a direct or topical exchange may significantly lower your network delays. You can read more about exchange types on the RabbitMQ website.

Your last question is about the wireformat. In theory RabbitMQ allows any string (or even binary) payloads, so its a matter of trying to squeeze more information into fewer bytes. In my experience, as long as your messages are not over network packet MTU, the gains of compression or choosing a clever encoding scheme are marginal.

In general, think of how much time you are spending on each optimization, and what is the expected ROI. IMO some optimizations are more useful than others.If I was you I would look very carefully at the RabbitMQ configuration parameters. For example, look if you can setup the rabbit MQ server with per-process message queues.